# Automatically macro starts and check some paraeters

Tags: excel, vba, foreach

i have a problem i want to resolve but i need help. I have an excel in which there are many information: `date, activity, people, hours`. Each person writes his job and so the table it's something like this

```
20/06/2013  football  me  8.00 
21/06/2013  football  me  8.00
22/06/2013  basket    me  8.00 
21/06/2013  football  me  8.00
22/06/2013  basket    me  8.00
```

From Monday to friday. The total hours must be 40 and all fields must be completed and none empty! I need a macro that starts automatically for example at 12.00 and check if it's all correct for each people inside the sheet. How can i do it? Someone can help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Also questions asking for code must show a minimal understanding of the problem being solved, some research and attempts. Youve demonstrated none of the above so I am voting to close as it stands,

Comment: unfortunatelly i don't have any code right now because it's almost first time i programming in vba. I need a "start" if possible. It's not so difficult the question; i have 4 cells: `date, activity, people, hours` every cell must be completed (not empty). The sum of hour from monday to friday must be 40. The macro could be launch automaticcaly but also through a button it's good for me.

Comment: so what are you trying to do? A macro that validates the fields? you want the macro to check all the fields are entered and if sum of hours  =40?

Comment: Exactly. The second step it's make these controls for each person inside the excel sheet. In meanwhile it's good the first thing

Comment: can you upload a sample of your spreadsheet or at least a screenshot? I wouldnt know if each person has their own spreadsheet or if they are all listed below each other - its hard to come up with a hint for you without seeing that info

Answer (score 0):

Assuming in each sheet, you have a row header in row 1, and the data in A2:D6. The following code should return error in the form of `msgbox` accordingly.

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim emp As Boolean
    Dim sum As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        emp = False
        For i = 2 To 6
            For j = 1 To 4
                If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, j)) Then
                    emp = True
                    'Skip the rest of cells
                    GoTo fHandler
                End If
            Next j
        Next i

fHandler:

        If emp Then
            MsgBox "Some entries are empty in " & ws.Name
        End If

        sum = WorksheetFunction.sum(ws.Range("D2:D6"))
        If sum <> 40 Then
            MsgBox "Total hours not equal to 40 in " & ws.Name
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```